# Adding the reverse of a list to its end

Tags: python-3.x

What's the special function in python that takes a list, or a string, and adds its reverse to the end:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

some_function(list):

output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]

or string = "1234"

function(string)
output = "1234321"
```

Comment: list += list [::-1]

Comment: Why isn't your output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]` ?

Comment: Use `list += list[-2::-1]` if you don't want the last element to be included in the reversal.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for both strings and lists :)

```
def my_reverse(iterable):
  for element in iterable[-2::-1]:
    iterable += element
  return iterable
```